# Lua Sandboxing - Eliminating Function Creation

Tags: lua, sandbox

I've read on the Lua wiki / here / etc. on how to sandbox lua code generally.  But I haven't been able to find something that disallows function creation.  For example, the example [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SandBoxes) provides a sample code as:

```
assert(run [[function f(x) return x^2 end; t={2}; t[1]=f(t[1])]])
```

And that's with an empty environment.  But I want to eliminate the ability to create a function (the 1st part of the code) - e.g., just allow expressions.  Any idea on how to do that?  Does it have to be in C somehow?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: If this is possible (I doubt it): Please don't do this. Not to mention that you'd remove an important part of the language (not of the library, *of the language* - as if an embedded device didn't support pointers in their weird C offshot!), that also means you'd severely damage the versatility and expressiveness of whatever scripts are written in your embedded Lua.

Comment: if you disallow functions, you disallow lambdas. if you disallow lambdas you disallow an entire class of simple expressions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to evaluate expressions only, you could try this:

```
function run(s) return loadstring("return "..s)() end
```

(error handling omitted)

This simple solution will prevent most `attacks', but not eliminate them because one can say

```
(function () f=function(x) print"hello" end end)()
```

which defines a new function named `f`.

Your best bet is to use a sandbox and not worry about what the user does to the environment, because it'll not be *your* environment.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked perfectly ... I bought PIL recently and saw that method when I was reading, but forgot about it.  Appreciate the insights / suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try detecting the creation of functions by looking for the string "function" before allowing the execution of the lua script. For example from your C/C++ backend.

If "function" appears throw a "you are not allowed to create functions" error and don't execute the code.

A couple notes:

- You might want to try to customize the detection a bit more - only throw errors if you detect function followed by blanks and an opening parenthesis, for example. I'm leaving that as an exercise.
- You should be aware that there are some standard lua functions that kindof *expect* the users to be able to create functions - for example, the `string` table has several of those. Without creating functions, it'll be very difficult for your users to work with strings (it is *already* difficult enough with functions...)

Comment: World of Warcraft uses a similar approach as this. It has a regular Lua sandbox that just prevents access to anything outside the program. It also has a second highly restrictive sandbox created inside the first one using just Lua and only allowing access to a predefined set of functions and features. It does this with `loadstring()` and checks if the string contains `function`, `{`, or `}` first to prevent creation of functions and tables.